# How to do addition between two dropdown menus containing 1-5?

Tags: php

This is the code I have so far. I'm trying to use two dropdown menus in my HTML form that contains a 1-5 each and simply add them using POST.

//action for dropdown menu addition

```
        $dropdownValueA = $_POST["dropdown1"];
        $dropdownValueB = $_POST["dropdown2"];          
        $valueone = 0;
        $valuetwo = 0;
        if ($dropdownValueA == "1a"){
            $valueone = 1;
        }
        if ($dropdownValueA == "2a"){
            $valueone = 2;
        }
        if ($dropdownValueA == "3a"){
            $valueone = 3;
        }
        if ($dropdownValueA == "4a"){
            $valueone = 4;
        }
        if ($dropdownValueA == "5a"){
            $valueone = 5;
        }
        if ($dropdownValueB == "1b"){
            $valuetwo = 1;
        }
        if ($dropdownValueB == "2b"){
            $valuetwo = 2;
        }
        if ($dropdownValueB == "3b"){
            $valuetwo = 3;
        }
        if ($dropdownValueB == "4b"){
            $valuetwo = 4;
        }
        if ($dropdownValueB == "5b"){
            $valuetwo = 5;
        }

        echo $valueone + $valuetwo;
```

Comment: Your logic looks OK (though verbose). Are both `$_POST` variables set correctly? You may want to check `isset($_POST["dropdown1"])` and `!empty($_POST["dropdown1"])`. If your variables are indeed coming through correctly, then you'll need to clarify further exactly what the problem is.

Comment: _Addition_ is done with the last line `$valueone + $valuetwo`, which you already have. How is that not sufficient? What else do you mean by "addition"?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your HTML code. Please edit it into your post!

Comment: @CTM please explain what is the problem with your code. Does it not compute correctly? Do you see an error message? It is currently unclear what you expect, and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally not clear what is your problem and what is not works as expected. But your code is... not good :) Maybe try something like

```
if( preg_match('/^([1-5])a$/', $dropdownValueA, $m) ) {
    $valueone = $m[1];
}
if( preg_match('/^([1-5])b$/', $dropdownValueA, $m) ) {
    $valuetwo = $m[1];
}

echo (int)$valueone + (int)$valuetwo;
```

Comment: What are you trying to suggest here? Yes, a few ifs are verbose, but the question is still better than using regex to match the keys of the inputs...

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers will always come first, this will be your best option.

```
$dropdownValueA = $_POST["dropdown1"];
$dropdownValueB = $_POST["dropdown2"];

$valueone = intval($dropdownValueA);
$valuetwo = intval($dropdownValueB);

echo $valueone + $valuetwo;
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/G1VFv) HERE